# Android: OnAudioFocusChange not getting called when browser video playback active

Tags: android, audio

I'm implementing an OnAudioFocusChange method that seems to be working just fine. Whenever the user starts playing a YouTube video for example, the method will get called and I'll pause a playing AudioTrack on my app.

However, whenever that same AudioTrack is playing and the user triggers what seem to me to be certain web elements that use audio, the OnAudioFocusChange method doesn't get called at all.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
OnAudioFocusChangeListener afChangeListener = new OnAudioFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Called!");
                if(focusChange == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS){
                        running = false;
                }
        }
};
```

If I open the YouTube app and play a video, the method will be called.

If I open Chrome and attempt to watch a video such as the one in this page:
http://m.neogaf.com/showthread.php?t=706667

The audio will overlap, and the method won't get called.

So, is there any way to detect audio coming from audio elements such as that one so that I can pause my AudioTrack and avoid overlapping audio?